# Validating empty UITextField

Tags: ios, uitextfield

i wanted to prompt user if they left out any of the UITextfield in my app. 
my below code doesn't work,

```
-(IBAction)SignUpclicked:(id)sender{
if ([passwordText.text isEqualToString:0] && [usernameText.text isEqualToString:0] && [AddressText.text isEqualToString:0] && [PhoneText.text isEqualToString:0]){

    alert = [[UIAlertView alloc]initWithTitle:@"Error" message:@"Please Fill all the Field" delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:@"Dismiss" otherButtonTitles:nil, nil];

}
```

your responses will be huge help.

Comment: Why you are comparing with 0  instead of "" ?

Comment: Do this, 1] Trim passowrd.text with white space, 2] compare it with empty string or check it's length with 0

Comment: @Jageen i tried @"" as while, no result shown.

Comment: also add [alert show] in if block

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here you go,

```
- (IBAction)SignUpclicked:(UIButton *)sender {
    if ([[self localtrim:passwordText.text] isEqualToString:@""] || [[self localtrim:usernameText.text] isEqualToString:@""] || [[self localtrim:AddressText.text] isEqualToString:@""] || [[self localtrim:PhoneText.text] isEqualToString:@""]){

        alert =  [[UIAlertView alloc]initWithTitle:@"Error" message:@"Please Fill all the Field" delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:@"Dismiss" otherButtonTitles:nil, nil];
        [alert show];
    }
}
-(NSString *)localtrim:(NSString *) text {
    NSCharacterSet *whitespaceSet = [NSCharacterSet whitespaceCharacterSet];
    NSString *trimString = [text stringByTrimmingCharactersInSet:whitespaceSet];
    return trimString;
}
```

Comment: Checking the length against 0 is better than checking against the empty string because it will work even if the text is `nil`.

Answer (score 0):

You could test the string length or compare it to an empty string.

```
if (text.length == 0) { ... }
```

OR

```
if ([text isEqualToString:@""]) { ... }
```

Answer (score 0):

**Step 1] Timing string with empty space.**
because if user enter white space, we have to remove it.

```
NSCharacterSet *whitespace = [NSCharacterSet whitespaceCharacterSet];
NSString *trimmedString = [passwordText.text stringByTrimmingCharactersInSet:whitespace];
```

**Step 2] Compare result string with it's length or empty string**

```
if(trimmedString.length == 0)
{
// String is empty
UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc]initWithTitle:@"Error" message:@"Please Fill all the Field" delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:@"Dismiss" otherButtonTitles:nil, nil];
[alert show];

}
else
{
// String is not empty
}
```

Comment: Checking the length against 0 is better than checking against the empty string because it will work even if the text is `nil`.